# Can I get discounts on London Buses with a National Railcard?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, london

I wish to use *Oyster pay as you go* after adding the discount entitlement of a 16-25 Railcard to my Oyster.

1. Will I get the 34% discount on individual bus journeys (on £1.45)?
2. Will I get the 34% discount on the daily price cap for buses (on £4.40)? If no, will the bus journey prices be an addition to the [discounted off-peak price cap (£4.60 for Zones 1-2)](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/assets/downloads/tube-dlr-lo-railcard-fares-jan-2014.pdf) if I achieved the cap by travelling on the tube earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

From [National Railcards & Gold Cards](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tickets/18343.aspx) on the TfL website:

> If you are eligible to buy one of the following National Railcards:
>
> - 16-25 Railcard
>
>   [...]
>
> You can get:
>
> - Discounts on some off-peak travel on Tube, DLR, London Overground and National Rail services in London

Not buses.

---

2.

From [Bus and tram](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tickets/fares-2014/29086.aspx) on the TfL website:

> [no mention of railcards]

So, no.

---

2 second part.

No. The price level of the daily cap is reduced because of your discount, but what the cap *covers* is the same.